# Mapping an Enum to form elements using struts2

Tags: java, struts2, jaxb, model-driven

I'm trying to create a form which contains a radio button that maps to a class that extends java.lang.Enum.

```
<s:form action="corp_low_save">
  <s:textfield label="Corporate Client Name" name="name"/>
  <s:radio list="clientStatus.status" name="clientStatus.status"/>
  <s:textfield label="Primary Address Street" name="primaryAddress.street"/>  
  <s:submit />
</s:form>
```

The Action implements ModelDriven and is making a new instance of the following object available via getModel():

```
public class com...Customer extends java.lang.Object{
    protected java.lang.String name;
    protected com...ClientStatus clientStatus;
    protected com...Address primaryAddress;
    public com...Customer();
    public java.lang.String getName();
    public void setName(java.lang.String);
    public com...ClientStatus getClientStatus();
    public void setClientStatus(com...ClientStatus);
    public com...Address getPrimaryAddress();
    public void setPrimaryAddress(com...Address);
}
```

Here are the rest of the relevant classes.  They were all generated by JAXB:

```
public class com...ClientStatus extends java.lang.Object{
    protected com...StatusString status;
    protected javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar since;
    protected java.lang.String business;
    public com...ClientStatus();
    public com...StatusString getStatus();
    public void setStatus(com...StatusString);
    public javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar getSince();
    public void setSince(javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar);
    public java.lang.String getBusiness();
    public void setBusiness(java.lang.String);
}

public final class com...StatusString extends java.lang.Enum{
    public static final com...StatusString NEW_CLIENT;
    public static final com...StatusString EXISTING_CLIENT;
    public static final com...StatusString RENEWAL;
    public static com...StatusString[] values();
    public static com...StatusString valueOf(java.lang.String);
    public java.lang.String value();
    public static com...StatusString fromValue(java.lang.String);
    static {};
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: tag
>   'radio', field 'list', name
>   'clientStatus.status': The requested
>   list key 'clientStatus.status' could
>   not be resolved as a
>   collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator
>   type. Example: people or people.{name}

Any ideas about what the problem could be?

**Edit:**
I think the issue is that ClientStatus is null.  Since I simply instantiated a new Customer() its fields are null.  This is a bummer because it requires me to encode duplicate information in two parts of my program.  I can do something like this in the view:

```
  <s:radio name="clientStatus.status"
       list="#{'NEW_CLIENT':'New Client',
               'EXISTING_CLIENT':'Existing Client',
               'RENEWAL':'Renewal'}"/>
```

Or, in the controller, I have to explicitly instantiate the fields of Customer that my view needs.  This also dashes my hopes of writing a general action that can process all sorts of JAXB objects by simply instantiating a given JAXB class and making it available via getModel().

Anyone have any ideas of how to recover from this unfortunate state of affairs?

**Edit 2:** Fixed the first form to what I would expect to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Revised Answer**

When the error message states:

> could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/**enumeration**/iterator type

It means a `java.util.Enumeration`, not an enum.

With that said, you can still use an enum, you just need to pass an array or collection of the values you want available. For example, `ClientStatus.values()`, which returns an array.

Just add a getter to your action called `getClientStatuses` that returns the array (or a collection) of all of the values.

**Original Answer**

The `list` attribute needs to take all of the enum values. In your first example, it doesn't look like that is occurring. Instead, you are providing `clientStatus`. Isn't that an individual enum value?

In your revised example, you are giving the `list` attribute a map, so it is working.

I usually expose the enum values in my action. e.g., `getClientStatuses`.

Comment: From the error message, I would think that it is OK to use an Enum: 'collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator'

Comment: I mean, don't you think you would always want to represent radio buttons with an Enum?

Comment: I revised my answer for clarity.